# Compare characters and return mismatches In R

Tags: r, compare

I want to compare characters  iteratively and return mismatches between 2 columns of a data frame.

It should not return if x2x, y67y, as x remains x and y remains as y.

**Input:**

```
x y    x_val              y_val
A  B   x2x, y67h, d7j  x2y, y67y, d7r
B  C   x2y, y67y, d7r  x2y, y67y, d7r
C  A   x2y, y67y, d7r  x2x, y67h, d7j  
C  D   x2y, y67y, d7r  x67b, g72v, b8c
D  E   x67b, g72v, b8c  x67r, g72j
```

I want to add a column val and return differences between x_val and y_val

**Output:**

```
x y       x_val             y_val           val
A  B   x2x, y67h, d7j  x2y, y67y, d7r     x2y, d7r
B  C   x2y, y67y, d7r  x2y, y67y, d7r     NA
C  A   x2y, y67y, d7r  x2x, y67h, d7j     y67h, d7j
C  D   x2y, y67y, d7r  y67b, g72v, b8c    y67b, g72v, b8c
D  E   y67b, g72v, b8c  y67b, g72j        g72j
```

I tried `xy_val <- y_val[!(y_val %in% x_val)]`

Could you please suggest solution on how to output mismatches.

**My data:**

```
structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), y = c("B", "C", "A", "D", "E"), x_val = c("x2x, y67h, d7j", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "y67b, g72v, b8c"), y_val = c("x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2x, y67h, d7j", "y67b, g72v, b8c", "y67b, g72j" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your data in `dput(mydata)` form? It's not entirely clear what's the format of your `x_val` and `y_val` variables. Are they comma separated strings? or vectors?

Comment: Good to know, but I'm not asking about what the data represents. I'm asking about the format of the data itself. "strings" as in string literals in programming.

Comment: f <- data.frame( x = c("A","B","C","C","D"), y = c("B","C","A","D","E"), x_val = c("x2x, y67h, d7j","x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r","y67b, g72v, b8c" ), y_val = c("x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2x, y67h, d7j", "y67b, g72v, b8c","y67b, g72j"))

Comment: structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "C", "C", "D"), y = c("B", "C", 
"A", "D", "E"), x_val = c("x2x, y67h, d7j", "x2y, y67y, d7r", 
"x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2y, y67y, d7r", "y67b, g72v, b8c"), y_val = c("x2y, y67y, d7r", 
"x2y, y67y, d7r", "x2x, y67h, d7j", "y67b, g72v, b8c", "y67b, g72j"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

Comment: Can anyone kindly help. The below code helps but it should also not return x2x, y67y as there is no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

f %>% mutate(diff_x = map2_chr(strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), 
                               strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), 
                               ~paste(grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', setdiff(.x, .y), 
                                           value = TRUE, perl = TRUE), 
                                           collapse = ", ")) %>%
               replace(. == "", NA), 
             diff_y = map2_chr(strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), 
                               strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), 
                               ~paste(grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', setdiff(.y, .x), 
                                           value = TRUE, perl = TRUE),
                                           collapse = ", ")) %>%
               replace(. == "", NA))
```

**Notes:**

1. `grep` takes the output of `setdiff` and removes any element with the format "same characters with digits in between"
2. `([a-z])` matches any alpha characters.
3. `(?>\\d+)` is an atomic group that matches digits of any length but does not backtrack.
4. `(?!\\1)` is a negative lookahead that matches whatever was matched by `([a-z])`

**Output:**

```
  x y           x_val           y_val    diff_x          diff_y
1 A B  x2x, y67h, d7j  x2y, y67y, d7r y67h, d7j        x2y, d7r
2 B C  x2y, y67y, d7r  x2y, y67y, d7r      <NA>            <NA>
3 C A  x2y, y67y, d7r  x2x, y67h, d7j  x2y, d7r       y67h, d7j
4 C D  x2y, y67y, d7r y67b, g72v, b8c  x2y, d7r y67b, g72v, b8c
5 D E y67b, g72v, b8c      y67b, g72j g72v, b8c            g72j
```

Comment: When I am trying to save this as X, the values in diff_x and diff_y are stored as list.                                                            
           X <-  f %>%
  mutate(diff_x = map2(strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), 
                       strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), setdiff),
         diff_y = map2(strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), 
                       strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), setdiff))

Comment: Thank you for the update. But I get the following error. Error in strsplit(x_val, split = ", ") : object 'x_val' not found

Comment: Figured it out, it must be f %>% instead of <- . I appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the mismatches should not be returned if x2x (no change - there is no mutation) like I showed it in the output of  3rd column:    y67h, d7j

[C  A   x2y, y67y, d7r  x2x, y67h, d7j     y67h, d7j]

Could you please help me with this @avid_useR. Thanks

Comment: @sdu We can add a `grep` inside `paste` to remove any strings with the format "same characters with digits in between"

Comment: @sdu We can just add a `replace`

Comment: Can you please help a follow-up question of my colleague. We still want to look for mismatches like here but with a slightly different dataset.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61039110/match-strings-before-special-character?noredirect=1#comment107993410_61039110

Answer (score 0):

does this deliver the desired results?

```
check_this = function(temp_data)
{
  print(temp_data)

  string_1 = gsub(", ", " ",   temp_data["x_val"])
  string_2 = gsub(", ", " ",   temp_data["y_val"])

  string_sub_1 = gsub(" ", "|", string_1)
  string_sub_2 = gsub(" ", "|", string_2)

  unmatche_s1 = gsub(string_sub_2, "", string_1)
  unmatche_s2 = gsub(string_sub_1, "", string_2)

  # return both as a list - if you need only unmachtedy_in_x you can just return(unmatched_s2)
  return(list(unmatchedx_in_y = unmatche_s1, unmatchedy_in_x = unmatche_s2))

}

res = apply(f, 1, check_this)
```