# Match strings before special character

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to match strings in two columns and return mismatches before ":". It should not return if x2x, y67y, as x remains x and y remains as y.

**I don't want to match the ":decimal". If x2y is in both columns then its a match (irrespective of the mismatch in the decimal after special character)**
INPUT:

```
input <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), x_val = c("x2x:0.12345,y67h:0.06732,d7j:0.032647", 
"x2y:0.26345,y67y:0.28320,d7r:0.043647", "x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28310,d7r:0.043547", 
"x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28330,d7r:0.043247"), y_val = c("x2y:0.33134,y67y:0.3131,d7r:0.23443", 
"x2y:0.34311,y67y:0.14142,d7r:0.31431", "x2x:0.34314,y67h:0.14141,d7j:0.453145", 
"x67b:0.31411,g72v:0.3134,b8c:0.89234")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Output:

```
output <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), x_val = c("x2x:0.12345,y67h:0.06732,d7j:0.032647", 
"x2y:0.26345,y67y:0.28320,d7r:0.043647", "x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28310,d7r:0.043547", 
"x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28330,d7r:0.043247"), y_val = c("x2y:0.33134,y67y:0.3131,d7r:0.23443", 
"x2y:0.34311,y67y:0.14142,d7r:0.31431", "x2x:0.34314,y67h:0.14141,d7j:0.453145", 
"x67b:0.31411,g72v:0.3134,b8c:0.89234"), diff_x = c("y67h:0.06732,d7j:0.03264", 
NA, "x2y:0.23435,d7r:0.043547", "x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28330,d7r:0.043247"
), diff_y = c("x2y:0.33134,d7r:0.23443", NA, "y67h:0.14141,d7j:0.453145", 
"x67b:0.31411,g72v:0.3134,b8c:0.89234")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I run into problem when I just want to match till ":" character. The following code is taken from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285959/5150629.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

I %>% mutate(diff_x = map2_chr(strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), 
                               strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), 
                               ~paste(grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', setdiff(.x, .y), 
                                           value = TRUE, perl = TRUE), 
                                           collapse = ", ")) %>%
               replace(. == "", NA), 
             diff_y = map2_chr(strsplit(x_val, split = ", "), 
                               strsplit(y_val, split = ", "), 
                               ~paste(grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', setdiff(.y, .x), 
                                           value = TRUE, perl = TRUE),
                                           collapse = ", ")) %>%
               replace(. == "", NA))
```

Can anyone help?Thanks!

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me the logic to generate `diff_x` and `diff_y`. Why `x2y:0.26345` or `d7r:0.043647` is removed in 2nd row?

Comment: Hi Ronak. Sorry I was not clear. They are same in both the columns. I don't want to match the special character and decimals after it.

Comment: So I am trying to match only x2y and d7r. Ignore the special character and the decimal.

Comment: your output is still not clear me. Can you explain it with an example? Take 1st and 2nd row for example.

Comment: This is a follow up question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55284306/compare-characters-and-return-mismatches-in-r/55285959?noredirect=1#comment97307933_55285959

Comment: I still want to do the same as in the link I shared. Only change is decimals

Comment: So the output should look for mismatches in alpha numeric. For example in 2nd column x_val - x2y:0.26345 ; y-val- x2y:0.34311. I want to match only alphanumeric part x2y and leave the rest of the string

Comment: x2y is a match. I am not interested in the decimal after the x2y

Comment: Does that help? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: In the 1st row - There is x2x, y67y. If the alphabet is same then its a match or ignore. 
Basically only compare the ones with different alphabets like y67h,d7j, d7r.

Comment: So we are comparing alphabets at a position which is number. In row1 d7j and d7r - If different alphabets at position 7 then mismatch.

Comment: Please provide your data in `dput` form directly in your question.

Comment: Input <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), y = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), x_val = c("x2x:0.12345,y67h:0.06732,d7j:0.032647", 
"x2y:0.26345,y67y:0.28320,d7r:0.043647", "x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28310,d7r:0.043547", 
"x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28330,d7r:0.043247"), y_val = c("x2y:0.33134,y67y:0.3131,d7r:0.23443", 
"x2y:0.34311,y67y:0.14142,d7r:0.31431", "x2x:0.34314,y67h:0.14141,d7j:0.453145", 
"x67b:0.31411,g72v:0.3134,b8c:0.89234")), row.names = c(NA, -4L
), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Your output has a `y67y:0.28330` in `diff_x`, should this not be removed?

Comment: It should be removed. Sorry its my fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55285959/5150629 to fit this question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    diff_x = map2_chr(
      strsplit(x_val, split = ","), 
      strsplit(y_val, split = ","), 
      ~ {
        setdiff(sub(":.+$", "", .x), sub(":.+$", "", .y)) %>%
          grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', ., value = TRUE, perl = TRUE) %>%
          sapply(grep, .x, value = TRUE) %>%
          paste(collapse = ", ") %>%
          replace(. == "", NA)
      }
    ),  
    diff_y = map2_chr(
      strsplit(x_val, split = ","), 
      strsplit(y_val, split = ","), 
      ~ {
        setdiff(sub(":.+$", "", .y), sub(":.+$", "", .x)) %>%
          grep('([a-z])(?>\\d+)(?!\\1)', ., value = TRUE, perl = TRUE) %>%
          sapply(grep, .y, value = TRUE) %>%
          paste(collapse = ", ") %>%
          replace(. == "", NA)
      }
    )
  )
```

**Output:**

```
  x y                                 x_val                                 y_val                     diff_x
1 A B x2x:0.12345,y67h:0.06732,d7j:0.032647   x2y:0.33134,y67y:0.3131,d7r:0.23443 y67h:0.06732, d7j:0.032647
2 B C x2y:0.26345,y67y:0.28320,d7r:0.043647  x2y:0.34311,y67y:0.14142,d7r:0.31431                       <NA>
3 C A x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28310,d7r:0.043547 x2x:0.34314,y67h:0.14141,d7j:0.453145  x2y:0.23435, d7r:0.043547
4 C D x2y:0.23435,y67y:0.28330,d7r:0.043247  x67b:0.31411,g72v:0.3134,b8c:0.89234  x2y:0.23435, d7r:0.043247
                                  diff_y
1               x2y:0.33134, d7r:0.23443
2                                   <NA>
3             y67h:0.14141, d7j:0.453145
4 x67b:0.31411, g72v:0.3134, b8c:0.89234
```

**Notes:**

1. Since we are only interested in comparing the first part of the string format `x1y:000000`, I added a `sub(":.+$", "", .x)` for each `map2_chr` input argument to strip out the `:000000` part first.
2. `setdiff` and the following `grep` steps work as expected to return the mismatches and exclude strings with the form `x1x`.
3. `sapply(grep, .x, value = TRUE)` after the first `grep` takes the vector of mismatches, and searches for their corresponding original strings (in `x1y:000000` form).
4. `paste` collapses the vector of mismatches into a single comma separated list.